# Precompiled JSX React,js is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am working through the React.js tutorials and I ran into a snag. When using React it works fine with the jsx transformer on my page. Once I remove that script and compile the jsx to js it no longer works. I'm using the jsx compiler that React recommends on their page. Here's my code:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uehqbdfL/)

```
<div id="content"></div>
<script src="https://fb.me/react-0.13.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/jsx">
    var CommentBox = React.createClass({displayName: "CommentBox",
        render: function() {
            return (
                    React.createElement("div", {className: "commentBox"},
                            "Hello, world! I am a CommentBox."
                    )
            );
        }
    });
    React.render(
            React.createElement(CommentBox, null),
            document.getElementById('content')
    );
</script>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<script type="text/jsx">
```

If you don’t use JSX, you should remove that type. Then it will work as expected. ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uehqbdfL/2/))

Comment: Wow thanks so much, I missed that in the tutorial. I just wasted an hour trying to figure out what the issue was!